# Click to populate Canvas Background with an Image?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, html5-canvas

I would like to create a button that when clicked a static image is displayed as the html canvas elements background?

How can I go about doing this?

Not sure if a stylesheet switcher is the right direction? Maybe there is a smarter solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#btnSet').click(function(){
           $('#canvas').css("background","url('plant1.jpg')");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="200">

</canvas>
<br/>
<button id="btnSet">Set Canvas BG</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

if all you want to do is display an image, you might as well use an img tag:

```
<script>
    function() setImage() {
        document.geTElementById("myImage").src = "myImage.jpg";
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="Set Image" onclick="setImage()"/>
<img id="myImage"/>
```

make sure myImage.jpg actually points to your image offcourse.